# JavaScript: what does "void 0" mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript, void

TypeScript [transpiles certain code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) into this:

```
Animal.prototype.move = function (distanceInMeters) {
    if (distanceInMeters === void 0) { distanceInMeters = 0; }
    ...
```

What's `void 0`? Is that the same trick as used for links `void(0)`? Why is not `undefined` used instead?

Comment: It's just used to not be affected if someone redefines `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `void` operator always evaluates as the undefined value.

The `undefined` variable, which defaults to holding the undefined value, can be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined primitive value, usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void 0”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).